# Make controller Transactional controller

Tags: grails

In my controller I have a action which updates 2 domain class.

I want it to make in such a way that if the second updates fails first update should roll back, basically if there is an error all the previous actions should roll back.

What's the basic idea here?

Answer (score 10):

If you don't want to move your logic to a Service (possibly because you may be calling multiple services to execute both of those updates), annotate your `controller action` with `@Transactional`.

```
public MyController {
 @Transactional
 def save(){
   myService.save(params)
   myOtherService.save(params)
   render "success"
 }

 ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the real solution. It is very often that I have to call more than one services in a controller and this seems to work perfectly in this scenario.

Comment: Great! Glad to help. If this or another answer was what you were looking for, please consider accepting an answer. Thanks!

Comment: While this may work, it is a smell in your code.   Seperation of responsibilites says that controllers shouldn't be responsible for transactions.  Make one service that calls the other two, then call that from the controller

Answer (score 7):

Just move all your business logic to services that already are transactional. Use one service for first update action and second for another action.

Answer (score 6):

Check out [services](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/services.html), they're transactional by default. Just do the updates there and if there's an error throw an exception and catch it in the controller