# Delete records in Grails service

Tags: grails, grails-services

In **Grails Service**, I have to delete records from the Db, but I get below error :

```
spi.SqlExceptionHelper, Connection is read-only. Queries leading to data modification are not allowed.
```

Although, there is `@Transactional(readOnly = false)` in my service, here is the delete part in my service code:

```
def adsDurationIs7 = null
adsDurationIs7 = Ads.findAllByDuration("7 days", [sort: "dateCreated", order: "asc"])
adsDurationIs7.each {
   Ads.get(it.id).delete(flush: true)
}
```

Comment: It seems that you are using a database user without write privileges. Try to check in you db server if the user has all grand that you need

Comment: @AlessandroChiarotto no i can delete with this user in some other parts of the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are executing this service function from controller's function, which is not transactional. Add **@Transactional** to controller's function.

Here is an example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21998182/2166188

Comment: `@Transactional(readOnly = false)`is already there in my service

Comment: Read my answer (and example) carefully: I'm talking about controller from which you're executing service's function.

Comment: Controllers should _not_ be transactional. There is no need to start a transaction outside of a transactional service - the service will handle that itself if it's properly configured/annotated.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why that's not working, but even if it did you're doing the work about as expensively as you possibly can. You load all of the instances into memory (including all non-lazy properties and collections), then for each one you get its `id` and use that to load the instance again with a `get` call (although if you're lucky and/or you have caching configured correctly this *might* be a no-op), and then use that to delete each database record one at a time. And you're ordering in the database, which adds processing time but is completely unnecessary since you're deleting everything that the query returns.

What you really want is GORM code that ends up running SQL similar to

```
delete from ads where duration=?
```

where the PreparedStatement sets the `?` parameter value to `"7 days"`.

This "where" query will do exactly that:

```
Ads.where { duration == '7 days' }.deleteAll()
```

as will this HQL update:

```
Ads.executeUpdate 'delete Ads a where a.duration = :duration',
                  [duration: '7 days']
```

So your service should look like

```
import grails.transaction.Transactional

@Transactional
class MyService {

   void deleteAdsDurationIs7() {
      Ads.where { duration == '7 days' }.deleteAll()
   }
}
```

or

```
import grails.transaction.Transactional

@Transactional
class MyService {

   void deleteAdsDurationIs7() {
      Ads.executeUpdate 'delete Ads a where a.duration = :duration',
                        [duration: '7 days']
   }
}
```